# Retrieving system specific values on windows platform

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I am developing a Windows specific application using C++. How can I obtain system specific information such as horizontal/vertical screen resolution, screen dpi, Geographic Location(United States, China, etc), System Language, Language of executing Process etc. I have used some methods to get the geographic location and language, but they return an ID instead of string. How can I get the String value.

The methods I used are:

```
GEOID id = GetUserGeoID(GEOCLASS_NATION);
LANGID lid = GetUserDefaultLangID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked several questions. They have been answered in other stack over flow questions.

[How to get screen resolution in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690619/how-to-get-screen-resolution-in-c) - how to get screen resolution

[How to get the current DPI of a system in MFC Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991546/how-to-get-the-current-dpi-of-a-system-in-mfc-application) - how to get DPI

You have provided your own answer for Geo location.

You have provided your own answer for system language.

It is normal to use these IDs to look up the information from a table. See this post. [Win32 API for getting the language(localization info) of the OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322578/win32-api-for-getting-the-languagelocalization-info-of-the-os)

I am not sure what you mean by "Language of executing process." If you mean the system language, you already have that answer. If you mean the language of an arbitrary application besides the one you are coding, I can't imagine that there is a single answer for that, and that in many cases you simply will not be able to get it.